# I need to process the log files daily on the app engine programmatically on the server side

Tags: google-app-engine, server-side, logfiles

My app runs on the google app engine
Till now I have been downloading log files and processing them into meaningful data afterwards using python

However, now for the use of management I would like to process the daily log files directly on the app engine so that the reports can then be directly send to the concerned people.....

Is this possible....Please suggest some method.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do exactly what you describe using [LogService API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logservice/).

> The google.appengine.api.logservice package provides methods allowing applications to periodically flush logs during long-running requests and to examine an application's request logs and application logs

Comment: Hmmmm....Thanks a lot...will be checking that.......
I was trying something called cron jobs........

Comment: Rignt. Cron Jobs too. With LogService you can *access* your logs from within the app code. So, if you want to, say, access it every morning at 5am, you'll definitely need a cron job too.

Comment: And what about the datastore indexes..... Is that also required for the log processing

Comment: Unless you're fetching log events and stuffing them into the Datastore - no. Indexes are related to Datastore operations only.

Comment: okkkkk......... have started working on google.appengine.api.logservice.......Thanks man